# Using field attribute in file name of PDF export of Data Driven Pages

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, export, pdf, data-driven-pages

I have made a script that iterates through a set of Data Driven Pages. Right now I have it that just the ID number of the data driven page is used in the file name to distinguish between each export. What I'm looking to do is instead of using the page ID number, I want to use an attribute from a specific field in the data driven page shapefile.

How do I accomplish this?

I've included my script below.

```
import arcpy

inputList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
bckGrndLyrs = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
outputLocation = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
exportDPI = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

for lyrs in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df):
    if lyrs.name in inputList:
        lyrs.visible = False
    elif lyrs.name in bckGrndLyrs:
        lyrs.visible = True  
    else:
        lyrs.visible = False

for inFC in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(inputList, "", df):
    if inFC.name in inputList:
        arcpy.AddMessage("Activating " + inFC.name + " Layer")
        inFC.visible = True
    
        for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
          mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
          for titleItem in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
              if titleItem.name == 'EditedTitle':
                arcpy.AddMessage("...Changing title to " + inFC.name + " " + str(pageNum))
                titleItem.text = inFC.name 
          arcpy.AddMessage("......Refreshing Dataframe")
          arcpy.RefreshTOC()
          arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
          arcpy.AddMessage(".........Exporting " + inFC.name + " Page " + str(pageNum) + " as PDF")
          arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, outputLocation + " " + inFC.name + " " + str(pageNum) + ".pdf", resolution=exportDPI)
        inFC.visible = False

del mxd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]

for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
        
mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
    
pageName = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.CoupeID3
        
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, r"C:\Temp\image" + str(pageName) + ".tif", df, df_export_width=1800, df_export_height=1500, geoTIFF_tags=True)
```

Where `CoupeID3` is whatever you want